# Find and Replace Regex with Jquery (or straight JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This is my sample string:

`<p>Whatever #591118</p>`

This is my desirable output:

`p='<p>Whatever <i class="dn">591118<i></p>';`

This is the regex I am trying to write:

`r="(.*)#([0-9]+(?=<))(<.*)$";`

If I:

`alert(p.match(r));`

It prints:

`<p>Whatever #591118</p>,<p>Whatever ,591118,</p>`

I was thinking to use `.replace` with `'$1<i class="dn">$2<i>$3'`

But my knowledge of regex and jquery ends here...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4kU4B/) what you are trying to do?

Comment: "I was thinking to use..." did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: God, it worked! Just change this: `var str = '<p>Whatever #591118</p>';`

Comment: Sorry for the big confusion with the sample string. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to replace part of the original string based on the regex being matched. The code (I think) is self explanatory.

```
var regex = /(.*)#([0-9]+(?=<))(<.*)$/; 
var str = '<p>Whatever #591118</p>';
var toReplace = '$1<i class="dn">$2<i>$3'; 

var result = str.replace(regex, toReplace);
console.log(result);
```

**Output:** `<p>Whatever <i class="dn">591118<i></p>`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4kU4B/1/)

**RegEx Explanation:** (for benefit of future readers)

`(.*)` - First capturing group (`$1`) which matches any number  of non-newline characters (zero or more). For the above example, this would be equal to `<p>Whatever`.

`([0-9]+(?=<))` - Second capturing group (`$2`) which is any string of characters starting with one numeric character (that is, 0-9) and a positive look ahead to capture all characters until a `<` character is encountered. For the above example, this would be equal to `591118`.

`(<.*)` - Third capturing group (`$3`) which is basically all remaining characters starting with the `<`. For the above example, this would equal to `</p>`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
^.*\/\/(\S+)\s+#(\d+)([^,]*).*$
```

Replacement string:

```
$1 <i class="dn">$2<i>$3
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gM9lW0/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `.*\/\/` It matches all the chars upto the `//`
- `(\S+)` Non-space characters are captured into a group.
- `\s+#` One or more spaces followed by `#` symbol.
- `(\d+)` One are more numbers are captured into another group.
- `([^,]*)` Captures any character not of `,` zero or more times.
- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Comment: Hey partner, would you be kind to explain us (miserable mortals) your regex?

Comment: ^.* begins with 0 or more any chars, \/\/ followed by //, (\S+) followed (catch $1) by 1 or more not white char (space, tab, newline...), \s+ followed by 1 or more white char, (\d+) followed (catch $2) by 1 or more digit , ([^,]*) followed (catch $3) by 0 or more any char but coma, .*$ ends with 0 or more any char. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp